# AWS MSK: how to pause?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-msk

I have provisioned a 3-broker MSK cluster on AWS.  Is there some way to pause the cluster?  The idea is that this is a cluster reserved for development purposes, and that to conserve our budget for cloud resources, we would intermittently halt the cluster (Eg, over weekends).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am afraid that this is not possible. MSK clusters are dedicated clusters created that are charged while the resources (brokers and storage) are being used. I would recommend destroying your cluster while not using it and recreating it once is necessary. You can do this programmatically using the CLI, AWS SDK, or using IaC tools like AWS CDK and Terraform.

**Update**: alternatively, you can also check whether [Amazon MSK Serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/msk/features/msk-serverless/) may suit your development needs.

Comment: I view the cluster as simply a union of its constituent servers.  If a solitary EC2 can be toggled off/on, to my thinking, so should a cluster.  I understand there may be conceptual challenges in what happens to all the data missed while the cluster is down.... I don't have a good answer for that.

Comment: You are not wrong by saying that underneath MSK is just a bunch of EC2 instances with block storage attached and therefore they could be paused. The problem is that MSK is a fully managed service, where the underlying infrastructure is abstracted away from you. This means that you don't control the lifecycle of resources but instead — you control the lifecycle of the service that in turn is built on top of those resources.

TL;DR: The limitation is not technical but about the way Amazon packages the product.

Comment: @RicardoFerreira, would you have some references on how to store and restore programmatically  the service using CLI, SDK or Terraform? (specially the 'storing' part is of interest). In my case the cluster/plugins/connectors were created on the GUI... so I don't have an initial IaaS code to reuse every Monday.
In other words, is there a way to 'export' the whole existing configuration into some files? (i.e. CloudFormation or Terraform format)

Comment: There are some tools you can use for this. One of them is https://former2.com that allows you to scan your AWS services from a browser plugin and then generate the IaC code. However, as an AWS employee, I can't advise you to use it. It might expose your account to security vulnerabilities that I can't even measure. My official answer is: write a Terraform code that represents the MSK cluster you want to import, then run the command `terraform import` providing the specific ID of the MSK cluster. Another option is using the AWS CLI to describe the MSK cluster, which will generate a JSON view.